# Is it bad practice to use same variable for two purpose in DTO

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, dto

```
@JsonRootName(value = "studentInfo")
@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class StudentInfo {
    private String student;
    @JsonProperty("address")
    private String address;

    @JsonProperty("studentName")
    public String getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    @JsonProperty("studentUserId")
    public void setStudent(String student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

This is my `Student` class I'm using this object in my student related API as DTO.
Here I've used the student String variable in such a way that when `POST/PUT/` API is called and studentUserId is passed it'll get set to student String variable but whenever StudentInfo object is returned as Response Entity then it'll return the actual name of Student which is stored in User table.

I just want to know that, the way I've used the student String variable and `@JsonProperty` for it, is correct way to use or its wrong practice?

Comment: Yes, it is bad practice. You should have a separate `userId` field in your class. Using the same field for different data is just bugs waiting to happen. It will also be really confusing when other people look at the class at a later time.

Comment: It is also a nightmare to write tests for that class if the semantics for a field depends on the context it is used in.

Answer (score 4):

Not only a rule for a DTO but for all classes, programs and languages *(basically in real non-academic life)*, when programming, each **variable and attribute has it's own purpose and used only for this**.

If you follow this rule you will follow also conventions about:

- **Naming**  (each variable will have a decriptive and unique name)
- **Readability** (not only you, also others will see and know how each variable is used for)
- **Maintanability** (when something change *-and **yes**, it will change-*, you won't need to divide or make uglies workarounds to make change or fix the problem)
- **Testability** it is a nightmare to write tests for class if the semantics for a field depends on the context it is used in. ([@Fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor))

And some others. Anyway, this are just conventions and not mandatory rules, the syntax will be confusing but correct, thus you can use it. My recommendation is: **don't!** `;)`

Comment: I'd like to add testability to that list.

Comment: You are right. Not impossible, but very ugly and complicated. Given the scenario in the question: I'd have to write the test so it takes into account the context (used as response / used as query). Of course, one could argue that field is only tested for that it contains the actual value I give it, but there may be more to it. So I am speaking on a general basis. A better example would be a numerical field with bounds. Based on context, it may have different valid bounds which had to be tested taking the context into account. Makes for an ugly instable test ... at least in my humble opinion.